Book for children/teenagers where the protagonist gets stuck in a time dilation-esque situation
I read this book when I was a child, probably 2010-2012, but of course the book could have been older. I don't expect it to be pre-2000, though. I read it in Dutch, in a library.
I know that the main character (MC) is male, though I think he had a female companion at some point; both in their early teens. The story took place in the real world, but the MC was experiencing time in a really odd way. I distinctly remember it being night for the MC, but on the road, he saw cars moving very slowly (because time was going much slower for them), surrounded by a bulb of light because it was still daytime for the people in the cars.
I also distinctly remember a scene where the MC looks down a well and gets a message from his future self and the girl he was with. At some point, future-MC and future-girl whisper to each other, and present-MC gets jealous. Some time later, the MC now has to give the message to his past self, and he whispers to his companion that he forgot his line, making her giggle and making him realise that that's what he saw his future self doing earlier too.
I also think there were evil creatures in this story with fish- or frog-like heads and possibly old (maybe Roman-style) armour.

Did you buy the book? Read it in a library? Read it online? Kindle?

Edited, thanks!

Ah, yeah, the language can definitely be a thing. :) Do you think that it was translated? We also have a longer list of questions here for ideas of what more to [edit] in. You've got a good start, though.
